# Hilbert scheme with essential generators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $H$ be the Hilbert scheme of finite flat lci subschemes in $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ of degree $d$, where $k$ is some field. In other words the set of morphisms from an affine $k$-scheme $Spec(A)$ to $H$ consists of surjections $A[t_1, \dots, t_n] \to B$ (up to the evident notion of isomorphism) with kernel generated by $n$ elements, such that $A \to B$ is finite locally free of degree d. (One knows that $H$ is smooth of dimension $nd$.) Let $U \subset H$ denote the subfunctor consisting of those maps $A[t_1, \dots, t_n] \to B$ such that $A[t_1, \dots, t_{n-1}] \to B$ is surjective (i.e. the last generator is unnecessary). I believe this defines an open subscheme of $H$ (essentially by Nakayama's lemma).

**Here is my question**: Write $Z \subset H$ for the (reduced) closed complement of $U$ in $X$. What can be said about $Z$? In particular, what is its codimension?

*Regarding the title*: Naively, $Z$ consists of those maps $A[t_1, \dots, t_n] \to B$ such that $A[t_1, \dots, t_{n-1}] \to B$ is *not* surjective. In other words, the last generator is essential.